# How to use templates with Nested class in C++

Tags: c++, templates, nested-class

I am trying to use templates for a nested class. I am not sure how to access the class type of the inner class from another class.

Sample Code below.

```
// I have a List class that can accept any type. It has an inner class
template <class T>
class List
{
    public:
        class Node
        {
            public:
                T       data;
                Node*   next;
                Node*   prev;
        };

        void addElement(Node& value);

    private:
        Node* head;
};

// Here I am making an array of Lists
template <class T>
class ListArray
{
    public:
        // Here is my question.
        void add(Node& value); // How to give "Node" class type here ?

    private:
        List<T> _listArr[10];
};

// Is the below the right way to define ListArray::add, especially the way in which Node type can be passed to it ?
template <class T>
void ListArray<T>::add(List<T>::Node& value)
{
    // Make a call to List::addElement and pass Node& value
    _listArr[0].addElement(value);
    //....
}
```

Could you kindly let me know how the above can be achieved ? Thanks.

Comment: What, something like `ListArray<int>::Node* myNode;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Node` is a nested type of a class template:

```
template <class T>
class ListArray
{
    public:
        typedef typename List<T>::Node Node_type;

        void add(Node_type& value); // Refer to it as Node_type

    private:
        List<T> _listArr[10];
};
```

And:

```
template <class T>
void ListArray<T>::add(typename ListArray<T>::Node_type& value)
{
    _listArr[0].addElement(value);
    //....
}
```

I used `typedef` to define local name for node type. It is very useful - now, clients of `ListArray` can write code, that uses `Node_type` explicitly (without knowing what it actually is). This technique is used heavily in `std` library - usually, `std::` types have *tons* of typedefs to allow writing flexible code.

Also, note the [`typename` keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/typename) - it is required in case of nested types of class templates. It indicates, that given name is the name of a type (without it, you should get a compiler error).

Comment: Thanks for the typename keyword.